# Failed to compile ./styles/globals.css:4:0 Module not found: Can't resolve './${imagesat}image-hero-mobile.png'

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am getting this error in

```
./styles/globals.css:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './${imagesat}image-hero-mobile.png'

Import trace for requested module:
./styles/globals.css
./pages/_app.tsx
```

I am using next js as framework this error is probally due to tailwindcss .
 `'./${imagesat}image-hero-mobile.png'` this line of code is only in one file that is

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import menuList, { menuListType, menuObjectType } from "./menu";
const imagesat = "/images/01introSectionPage/";
const clients = [
    "client-audiophile.svg",
    "client-databiz.svg",
    "client-maker.svg",
    "client-meet.svg",
];

const IntroSectionDropdown = () => {
    return (
        <>   {/* <div className="right">
                        <div
                            className={`bg-[url('${imagesat}image-hero-mobile.png')] md:bg-[url('${imagesat}image-hero-desktop.png')]  h-32 w-32 bg-no-repeat bg-cover`}
                        >
                            <span className="sr-only">Hero image</span>
                        </div>
                        <img
                            src={`${imagesat}image-hero-desktop.png`}
                            alt=""
                            className="hidden md:block"
                        />
                        <img
                            src={`${imagesat}image-hero-mobile.png`}
                            alt=""
                            className="md:hidden"
                        />
                    </div> */}
        </>
    );
};
export default IntroSectionDropdown;
```

If i commmet the `@tailwind utilities;` in globals.css then website goes on but without it tailwind is not complete.
Where i used the  `'./${imagesat}image-hero-mobile.png'` is commented the also getting error.
i had tried removing tailwind and reinstalled
i had cleard the next cache
I hope anyone has solution
REPO - https://github.com/Chandraprakash-Darji/frontend-mentor-challenges

Comment: What happen if you just write it directly without using template literals, it that work?

Comment: @AhmadShiddiq Yes. I have the same issue, and it works with the actual value, but when using a template literal is errors out. I'm also having this issue, after completely disconnecting any reference to the variable at all. I ran `npm i` and `npm run dev`, to hopefully reinitialize any broken things. I still can't seem to figure anything out.